# CSS: How do I select CSS for all the <li> elements that do have not been styled yet?

Tags: css

So I've marked up some of the edge cases in my list (first, second, last, and the last odd child) like so:

```
/* First and second elements */
li:first-child, li:first-child + li {
    ...
}

/* Last odd and last elements */
li:last-child {
    ...
}

/* CSS for second last list element, only when it's odd. */
li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd) {
    ...
}
```

How do I select identical CSS for all the remaining elements? And could you walk me through the process so I know how to do it next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define `li` styles. The psuedoclass will override those styles because of specificity rules.